# Another Sticky footer issue. 100% width div with repeating bg and div floated to the right

Tags: css, xhtml, sticky-footer

I know this question is an old one but having researched and tried and tried for 2 days now i am still not having any luck and I hope someone here could give me some advice!

Problem:

I have a page that i need to apply a sticky footer, simple normally but here's where i'm having the problem.

I can get the footer div(#footer) to stick to the bottom with out a problem (it's 100% width with a repeating background image) Then within this DIV I float another(#cut) with a bg-image to the right( the scissors in my example). This also works fine.

The problem is that I need another 100% width div(#footer-link-wrap) below the primary one so that I can float some nav links(#links) in the centre. Within the #footer-link-wrap i need another image floated all the way to the right, tried doing this with a positioned background but i can't get it to work.

I've totally hit a wall and I would greatly appreciate any feedback, i've just getting back into design after a long break and it's probably me making a silly mistake.

css as follows:

```
* {
margin:0;padding:0;
} 


html, body {

 height: 100%;
 background-color:#000;
 }

#wrap {
 min-height: 100%;
 }

#main {
 overflow:auto;
 padding-bottom: 60px;
 }  

#footer {
 position: relative;
 margin-top:-20px; 
 height: 20px;
 clear:both;
 width:100%;
 background:url(foot-hair.png) repeat-x;
 background-position:0 8px;
}

#cut{
 float:right;
 width:40px;
 height:20px;
 background: url(haircut.png);
}

#footer-link-wrap{

 margin-top:-40px; 
 height:40px;
 width:100%;
 background:url(hair-fall.png) no-repeat;
 background-position:bottom right;

 }

#links{
 position:relative;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 width:800px;
 background-color:#fff;
 }

/*for opera
body:before {
content:"";
height:100%;
float:left;
width:0;
margin-top:-32767px;
}*/`
```

Here's a link to the example [float help](http://d-syne.com/float)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have tou tried this implementation: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

**Update:**

here are the problems I found:

- you haven't set properly the basic
  configuration for the sticky footer
  according to the specification. The
  padding-bottom of #main was not the
  same as the height of the footer;
- You used float when you could just have used text-align for you #links #footer-link-wrap divs.
- Some other little things that i can't remember, try using this css sheet instead.

```
/*
Sticky Footer Solution
by Steve Hatcher
http://stever.ca
http://www.cssstickyfooter.com
*/

* {margin:0;padding:0;}

/* must declare 0 margins on everything, also for main layout components use padding, not
vertical margins (top and bottom) to add spacing, else those margins get added to total height
and your footer gets pushed down a bit more, creating vertical scroll bars in the browser */

html, body {height: 100%;}

#wrap {min-height: 100%;}

#main {overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom: 60px;}  /* must be same height as the footer */

#footer {position: relative;
    margin-top: -60px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 60px;
    clear:both;}

/*Opera Fix*/
body:before {/* thanks to Maleika (Kohoutec)*/
content:"";
height:100%;
float:left;
width:0;
margin-top:-32767px;/* thank you Erik J - negate effect of float*/
}




/**********************************
*** Start of your modifications ***
***********************************/
html, body {
background-color:#000;
}

#footer {
background:url(http://www.d-syne.com/float/foot-hair.png) repeat-x;
}

#cut{
width:100%;
height:20px;
background: url(http://www.d-syne.com/float/haircut.png) no-repeat bottom right;
}

#footer-link-wrap{
height:40px;
width:100%;
text-align: center;
background:url(http://www.d-syne.com/float/hair-fall.png) no-repeat bottom right;
 }

#links{
text-align: left;
margin: 0 auto;
width:800px;
background-color:#fff;
color: black;
}
```

good luck.

Comment: Hi, that's exactly where i got the original code from, it works fine with the single DIV but i'm stumped when it comes to multiple DIV's

Comment: Its not the solution, but maybe it could help you. Your image on #footer-link-wrap doesn't seem to show because the height of #footer-link-wrap is too small. Try changing the margin-top and height to 100 px and you can see it.

Comment: Does it look like what you wanted With a clear:both on #footer-link-wrap?

Comment: In #footer-link-wrap the image is only 40px high so that should be enough. The clear:both on #footer-link-wrap has moved the DIV under #footer(in FF,Crome & Opera) but the lower is displayed off the page i.e. you have to scroll to see it. In IE6 #footer-link-wrap still displays above the #footer div. Thank you for you're help so far, we're getting there!

Comment: Could you send a visual demo of how you want the div positionned (screenshot or visual representation using pipe and line in a text file).

Comment: thanks yvoyer, i have uploaded examples with descriptions to http://www.d-syne.com/floathelp i hope they explain it well!